# why -vm taking two vales in eclipse.ini?

Tags: eclipse

I have added the following in eclipse.ini before -vmargs:

-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\javaw.exe

But when I run I get an error 13. I am seeing two vm in the error log. How do I keep only one? Below is the error.[image: error]

Below is eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.600.v20191014-2022.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1100.v20190907-0426
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

Comment: Check the `eclipse.ini` file. It looks like *something* did a bad job of editing it. `-vm` should always be on its own line, and the path to the `java.exe` on the next line.

Comment: I have placed the path on new line. But when it executes it comes on the same line.

Comment: The error dialog isn't exactly the contents of the file. Show us the file contents.

Comment: @nitind I have added it

Comment: Having `--launcher.defaultAction
openFile` twice is probably bad, and `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM` isn't valid before Java 9. Remove the duplicate line and that last one.

Comment: Under Windows be sure to place double quotes (") around your java path: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\javaw.exe" because the path contains spaces.